# How to vertical align on ul list?

Tags: html, css

I have the following navigation bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/TTsvv/3/

My problem is that I can't seem to vertical align my `project/department/employee/contact` bar with my first image on the left. I have tried many methods but no luck. Can someone please help me out on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks to me like you just needed to add the same class='nav-vert' to the first img, does this solve your problem?

```
 <img  class='nav-vert' src='http://i42.tinypic.com/2nq5ic3.jpg'/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jd6p5/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `class='nav-vert'` to your first image. Check the updated code:

http://jsfiddle.net/TTsvv/6/